# python interpreter with ellipsis _ function?

Tags: python

```
>>> type(_)
<type 'ellipsis'>

>>> 1 + 1
2
>>> _
2
>>>
```

what's the usefulness of this _ function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just makes it easier to track intermediate values or to operate on the previously returned value.

```
>>> [x*x for x in range(5)]
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
>>> sum(_) # instead of having to type sum([0,1,4,9,16]) by hand
30
```

Comment: so, its not better declare a variable var = [x*x for x in range(5)] sum(var) instead use _?

Comment: i should agree that its usefull when you are using the interpreter as calculator but for test pieces of code i think its a bad pratice.

Comment: The idea is to use it for quick interactive calculations such as this.

Comment: @killown: The point is that it's interactive.  Sure, in thought-out production code, you would use proper variables, but at the REPL, you sometimes call `GetAFoo()` and only once you have received its value are you aware that you need to call its `.Bar()` method.  This is the point of the `_` in interactive Python.

Comment: `_` is *only defined in interactive mode*.

Answer (score 0):

in case you use ipython it's part of ipythons [output caching system] - it just stores the previous output.

**edit:** oh, it seems to be implemented for the default python interpreter as well.